# Pass query string parameters from WSO2 api gateway to AWS lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I need to pass query string parameters calling a WSO2 api gateway that calls an AWS lambda function.

I created the following lambda function in NodeJS in AWS:

```
  exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({
            incoming:JSON.parse(event), 
            date: new Date(), 
            context: JSON.parse(context)
            
        }),
    };
};
```

Then I:

- created a new API in wso2 publisher portal
- added an endpoint of type lambda
- configured a resource `getTest` for `GET`
- added a query parameter `parameter` to the `GET` resource

When I call my API here is the result:

```
curl -X GET "https://localhost:8243/lambda/1/getTest?parameter=myValue" -H "accept: */*" -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4="

{
    "statusCode":200,
    "body":"{\"incoming\":{},\"date\":\"2021-06-22T08:09:36.027Z\",\"context\":{\"callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop\":true,\"functionVersion\":\"$LATEST\",\"functionName\":\"wso2get\",\"memoryLimitInMB\":\"128\",\"logGroupName\":\"/aws/lambda/wso2get\",\"logStreamName\":\"2021/06/22/[$LATEST]90a7f95746c644a7a5cc61ec8648228e\",\"invokedFunctionArn\":\"arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:659641230079:function:wso2get\",\"awsRequestId\":\"4e271442-6209-47d9-ab0c-277c6535b8bd\"}}"
}
```

**How can I retrieve the `parameter` with value `myValue` in the lambda function?**

Answer (score 0):

You have to define you OpenAPI definition with this two kind of parameters:

- Path Parameter
- Query Parameter

I'll use wso2apim 2.6.0 and OpenAPI 2.0 definition...

Go to the /publisher and "Add a new API" with the "Design a New REST API"

Add a name , a contest ( ex. /mylambda ), and so on.
In the "API Definition" include a URL Pattern like
"/{id}/getTest" and check de GET method. Automatically a "Path parameter" is added with name "id".

[image: Set a path parameter]

Then add a new parameter named "parameter"

[image: Set the query parameter]

Save and in the implementation, set the "Endpoints" set the URL to:

"https://localhost:8243/lambda"

And that's all.

Comment: Hi @falconmfm the problem is that I don't receive that value in the lambda function.

Comment: In the api manager configure the correct logs to check the request and response, Go to Configure ( on the left ) -> logging , and enable debug mode in all the loggers that contains "wire" :  `httpclient.wire.content
httpclient.wire.header
org.apache.http.wire
org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire` and review de wso2carbon.log @da

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in the latest pack. You can send path/query/header parameters, http method, and path along with the payload to Lambda. Make sure you  define the parameter names at resource creation time as in 8.b.iii in [1]. Following is the format of the event object which Lambda receives.

```json
{
    "headers": {},
    "pathParameters": {},
    "queryStringParameters": {},
    "body": {},
    "httpMethod": "",
    "path": ""
}
```

Note that, to enable param mapping for earlier versions, you have to put following config to `deployment.toml` file.

```
[apim.lambda_mediator_config]
pass_request_params = true
```

[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/create-api/create-rest-api/create-a-rest-api/